# compact set $A \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with each intersection $\{c\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ being measure zero is measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-manifolds

It's Lemma 6.2 in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*(See [Do we need compactness hypothesis in Lemma 6.2 in Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3928383/do-we-need-compactness-hypothesis-in-lemma-6-2-in-lees-introduction-to-smooth) too):

> **Lemma 6.2** Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact subset whose intersection with $\{c\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ has $(n-1)$-dimensional measure zero for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $A$ has $n$-dimensional measure zero.

As the author said, this result follows easily from Fubini's theorem, but he also gives an elementary proof using sequential compactness, which does not depend on measure theory.

I am seeking some alternative elementary proof that follows from the finite open covering property rather than the sequential compactness directly. I tried to use Lebesgue's number theorem but it seems not working.

Thanks!

Edit: I attached a screenshot from [LeeSM]'s chapter 6

[image]

Comment: I think measurability will suffice, compactness is not necessary for the result.

Comment: There is no Lemma 6.2 in my 2003 copy.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks. yeah that's the case. I am just seeking some alternative elementary proof. I am not quite skilled using sequential compactness. I like the "finite covering" version of compactness.

Comment: @copper.hat It should be in the 2nd edition. I attched a screenshot.  I hope that's  not violating the copyright. Thanks.

Comment: The result is just saying that if $\{c\} \times A_c \subset U$ where $U$ is open, then there is some open interval $J_c$ such that $A \cap (J_c \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}) \subset U$. It is sort of a 'continuity' result.