# Lemma 6.2 Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

Tags: manifolds, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I am trying to understand how to apply Fubini's Theorem to the following lemma

> Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact subset whose intersection with $\left\{ c \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ has $n-1$-dimensional measure zero for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $A$ has $n$-dimensional measure zero.

The author claims this lemma follows easily from Fubini's theorem. I was trying trying to spot how to apply the theorem by observing

$$
A = \bigcup_{c \in \mathbb{R}} \left(\left\{ c \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \right) \cap A
$$

So $m(A) = m(\bigcup_{c \in \mathbb{R}} \left(\left\{ c \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \cap A\right))$ (here $m$ is the Lebesgue measure) but I don't know if this is any useful (I guess I was trying to write $A$ as product space so I could apply the theorem, but it doesn't look like I am going anywhere with this.

Can you maybe explain how to apply the theorem?

Comment: Integrate the indicator function $\chi_A$ on $\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$ using Fubini. It is almost instant.

Comment: $$m(A) = \int_{A} dm_n  = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_A dm_n = \int_{\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \chi_A dm_n = \int_{\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \chi_A d(m \times m_{n-1}).$$ I think from here there's an order of the integrals which should highlight the measure of the set of measure $0$. But I simply cannot see it.

Comment: Order the integrals so that what you know is the first thing you can use. You even wrote that essentially in the question itself!

Comment: And come on. There are 2 ways of doing the integrals. What's the worst that can happen if you choose the wrong one on your first try? Then you'll know for sure the second is the way to go. And afterwards you'll gain just that little bit more intuition with Fubini and its choice of ordering.

Comment: Also the proof is here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3928383/do-we-need-compactness-hypothesis-in-lemma-6-2-in-lees-introduction-to-smooth?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question, since I was encouraged to do so, however I think my use of notation isn't correct and it would be great if anyone would check. I'll denote with $m_n$ the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure and $\chi_A$ the characteristic function of the set $A$. Now we have

$$
m_{n}(A) = \int_{A} dm_n = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \chi_A dm_n = \int_{\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \chi_A dm_n = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \chi_A d(m \times m_{n-1}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \chi_A dm_{n-1} \right) \times dm = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \chi_A(x^1,\ldots,x^n) dm_{n-1}(x^2,\ldots,x^n) \right) \times dm(x^1) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{A \cap \left\{ x^1 \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}}  dm_{n-1}(x^2,\ldots,x^n) \right) \times dm(x^1) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} m_{n-1}(A \cap \left\{ x^1 \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}) d_m(x^1)
$$

By hypothesis we have

$$
m_{n-1}(A \cap \left\{ x^1 \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}) = 0
$$

So we have  $m_n(A) = 0$

My only doubt is the writing of

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \chi_A d m_{n-1} = \int_{A \cap \left\{ x^1 \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}} dm_{n-1}
$$

Is it correct?

I think I can justify by defining the family of functions $\left\{ \varphi_{x^1} \right\}$ where
$$
\varphi_{x^1} : \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \to A\cap\left\{ x^1 \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}
$$
for every $x^1 \in \mathbb{R}$ this is defined as $\varphi_{x^1}(x^2,\ldots,x^n) = \left( x^1,x^2,\dots, x^n \right)$

With this definition I can write
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \chi_A d m_{n-1} = \int_{\varphi_{x^1}^{-1} (A\cap\left\{ x^1 \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1})} \chi_A \circ \varphi_{x^1} (x^2,\ldots,x^n) d \left( m_{n-1} \circ \varphi_{x^1}\right)(x^1,x^2,\ldots,x^n) = \int_{\varphi_{x^1}^{-1} (A\cap\left\{ x^1 \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1})} \chi_{\varphi_{x^1}^{-1} (A\cap\left\{ x^1 \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1})} (x^2,\ldots,x^n) d \left( m_{n-1} \circ \varphi_{x^1}\right)(x^1,x^2,\ldots,x^n) = \int_{\varphi_{x^1}^{-1} (A\cap\left\{ x^1 \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1})} d \left( m_{n-1} \circ \varphi_{x^1}\right)(x^1,x^2,\ldots,x^n) = \left( m_{n-1} \circ \varphi_{x^1}^{-1} \right) (A\cap\left\{ x^1 \right\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1})
$$

I think this looks more correct, but I am still in doubt... I think I am getting closer anyway.

Comment: Wrong notation. It it more complicated: for each $x_1\in\Bbb{R}$, we have $\int_{\Bbb{R}^{n-1}}\chi_A(x_1,\cdot)\,dm_{n-1}=\int_{\text{pr}_{\Bbb{R}^{n-1}}(A\cap (\{x_1\}\times\Bbb{R}^{n-1}))}\,dm_{n-1}$, where $\text{pr}_{\Bbb{R}^{n-1}}$ takes a tuple in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and spits out the last $n-1$ entries. Just think about it: your $A$ lives in $\Bbb{R}^n$ so intersecting with a subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ still gives you a subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$, NOT $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$, though it is contained in a 'translated hyperplane'. The projection just makes things precise and ensures everything is right.

Comment: Or you can just say that for each $x_1\in\Bbb{R}$, the function $y\mapsto \chi_A(x_1,y)$ defined on $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$ is equal to zero $m_{n-1}$-a.e by hypothesis.

Comment: That's what I worked out just now. I was about to update my answer.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I've updated the answer... se if it is better (I think I am closer). The reason I think I am closer is because I am interpreting now the statement of the theorem in terms of pull back measure.

Comment: I already told you the correct way of writing it. There's no need to talk about pullback measures or anything. I gave you the literal, set-theoretically correct way of writing the equality. The hypothesis of the theorem is that for each $c\in\Bbb{R}$, we have $m_{n-1}\bigg(\text{pr}_{\Bbb{R}^{n-1}}\left(A\cap \left(\{c\}\times\Bbb{R}^{n-1}\right)\right)\bigg)=0$ (compactness of $A$ is irrelevant here).

Comment: I think there's need instead since you didn't write anything different from me and you're implicity using it anyway.

Comment: your equal signs aren't right. If you're going to involve the pushforward measure (not pullback btw), then you have to do it properly. If you use the pushforward measure, then you had better integrate over $\{x^1\}\times\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$, and at this stage, if you use the pushforward measure, you're going to need to invoke a change-of variables theorem (have you proven it?). Completely unnecessary terminology here. My first comment has the only equal sign you'll need (convince yourself that the equal sign I wrote really is as simple as I say it is).

Comment: Ok, I won't argue anymore. I'll eventually ask a separate question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: if you want to write with the $\phi_{x^1}$ notation, we can do that as well but the correct way to do it is $\int_{\Bbb{R}^{n-1}}\chi_A(x_1,\cdot)\,dm_{n-1}=\int_{\Bbb{R}^{n-1}}\chi_{\phi_{x^1}^{-1}\left(A\cap \left(\{x^1\}\times\Bbb{R}^{n-1}\right)\right)}\,dm_{n-1}$, and this is because because the two integrands are the same function on $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$. Note the slight difference with what you wrote. This is now equal to $m_{n-1}(\phi_{x^1}^{-1}(A\cap \{x^1\}\times \Bbb{R}^{n-1}))=0$ (your final equal sign). So, you definitely have the right idea, just not the notation.

Comment: You don't change the measures in the middle. It stays as $dm_{n-1}$ throughout. Also, $\int_{\Bbb{R}^{n-1}}$ stays as it is. Only the integrand is modified when we try to write $\chi_A(x^1,\cdot)$ as $\chi_{\text{something in $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$}}$.

Comment: I thought I was changing the measure from $m_{n-1}$ to $m_{n-1} \circ \varphi_{x^1}^{-1}$, no?

Comment: you don't need to, and you shouldn't. We're just re-expressing the function $\chi_A(x^1,\cdot)$ as $\chi_{\text{something}}$ so that integrating this over $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$ with respect to $m_{n-1}$ gives $m_{n-1}(\text{something})$. The "something" here is equal to $\phi_{x^1}^{-1}(\text{something else})$. So, it only at the end that you get the new measure $m_{n-1}(\phi_{x^1}^{-1}(\text{something else}))$.